# Script in package.json with type:"module" and typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, ecmascript-6, babeljs, package.json

I have the following situation:

1. I need to have `"type": "module"` in my `package.json` (ok)
2. I have a `.tsx` file that I need to execute as a script. Eg: `yarn myScript` (ok)
3. Windows OS (ok)
4. Node 14.17 (ok)

The problem is that it seems to be harder than it looks.

I have tried the following:

1. Running with `ts-node` produced:

   > `Error: Unknown file extension ".tsx"`
2. Running with `node --loader ts-node/esm` produced:

   > `Error: const err = new ERR_UNSUPPORTED_DIR_IMPORT(path, fileURLToPath(base));`
3. Defining `"esModuleInterop": true` in `tsConfig` resulted in nothing being changed.
4. Trying to transpile with babel and then run node produced:

   > `Error: require is not defined`
5. Trying to transpile with typescript resulted in many `node_modules` errors.

Does anyone have any idea or suggestions?